# Display row only if certain conditions are met

Tags: html, angular, datatable, ngx-bootstrap

I'm a intern, and I need some help.

I've a ngx-datatable, and I want to display row when condition are met. How can I do it? For example, if country covered is America, I display, if not, I didn't.

```
<ngx-datatable class="table-zenmoov" [columnMode]="'force'" [rows]="rows" [rowHeight]="'auto'"
      [headerHeight]="'auto'" [footerHeight]="'auto'" [externalPaging]="true" [count]="paginationInfo.totalElements"
      [loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator"
      [offset]="paginationInfo.currentPage" [limit]="paginationInfo.pageSize" (page)="setTablePage($event)"
      (sort)="onSort($event)">

      <ngx-datatable-column name="Name" [prop]="'first_name'" [sortable]="true">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          <div class="user-wrap">
            <div class="zenmoov-vendor" [style.background]="row.company_id?'#f0ad4e':'#5bc0de'"></div>
            <div class="img-circle img-wrapper vendor-avatar">
              <img *ngIf="row.avatar_url" [src]="row?.avatar_url " alt="logo">
            </div>
            <ng-container *ngIf="auth.userRID=='admin'">
              <a [routerLink]="['../../vendor/',row._id]">{{ row?.first_name }} {{ row?.last_name }}</a>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="auth.userRID=='hr'">
              <a [routerLink]="['../../../vendor/',row._id]">{{ row?.first_name }} {{ row?.last_name }}</a>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="auth.userRID=='talent'">
              <a [routerLink]="['/talent/vendor/',row._id]">{{ row?.first_name }} {{ row?.last_name }}</a>
            </ng-container>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>

      <ngx-datatable-column name="Company" [sortable]="false">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          {{ row?.company_name }}
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datable class>
```

Comment: Could you supply the object structure contained within the `rows` variable?

Comment: Why not use a pipe on the data (in the TS) for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngIf` on `html` element and it will be displayed only if the conditions are met.

Comment: I never used `ngx-datatable` but that does not look a good solution to me because if he use some sort of pagination (which it looks like it), it will probably mess that up. Idealy, he should filter the dataset before handing it to the `ngx-datatable` component.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `ngx-datatable` however, from a quick look into the documentation and your code I think I got it. I suppose that this bit `[rows]="rows"` is where you feed your data to the datatable, what you need to do is filter out the objects you don't want to be in the datatable, something like this in your TypeScript file:

**TypeScript File**

```
// Array of strings that contains all countries in America
const americaCountries = [...];
// Iterate over each row and verify if the country of that row is in the array americaCountries
// If it is, that row is added to a new array named americaRows
this.americaRows = this.rows.filter(row => americaCountries.includes(row.country));
```

**HTML File**

```
[rows]="americaRows"
```

Bear in mind that this is pseudo code because I don't know your TypeScript code and the rows object structure.